# what do these liferay config params actually mean?

Tags: file-upload, configuration, liferay

In my portal-ext properties file, I found these parameters. I don't remember why I put them into the config-file, I think I simply copied them from some other web page where someone said it'll help.

There are comments explaining what the parameters do, but I still don't understand the underlying issues.

How can uploaded data be serialized extraneously?

Why are files > 10 MB be considered excessively large, and why do they have to be cached?

```
#Set the threshold size to prevent extraneous serialization of uploaded data.

com.liferay.portal.upload.LiferayFileItem.threshold.size=262144

#Set the threshold size to prevent out of memory exceptions caused by caching excessively 
#large uploaded data. Default is 1024 * 1024 * 10.

com.liferay.portal.upload.LiferayInputStream.threshold.size=10485760
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These properties will be invoked when you have an external file upload functionality in your portal.

When you upload a larger file, it needs to be written to a temporary file on the disk.

Since the part of the file upload process is to hold the file in memory before writing it to the disk/database, Larger files must be avoided and it will prevent out of memory exceptions.

If you want to know more details on this,

Please go through this [link.](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html)

Liferay's Document Library uses other properties to restrict the file size. Such as

```
 dl.file.max.size=3072000
```

Answer (score 1):

These properties are connected with maximum file size for upload (e.g. for document library). However these seem to be the default values.